Why can't we define arbitrarily large sets yet after defining these axioms? (Tao's Analysis I)
In Tao's Analysis I I am very confused why he says we do not have the rigor to define arbitrarily large sets after defining the below 2 axioms:

Axiom 3.4 If $a$ is an object, then there exists a set
$\{ a \}$ whose only element is $a$, i.e., for every object $y$, we have $y \in \{ a\}$ if and only if
$y = a$


Axiom 3.5 (Pairwise union). Given any two sets $A, B$, there exists a set $A \cup B$, called the union of $A$ and $B$, which consists of all the elements which belong to $A$ or $B$ or both. In other words, for any object $x$,
$$
x \in A \cup B \Longleftrightarrow(x \in A \text { or } x \in B) .
$$

(Prior to this point Tao mentioned the axiom of extension and axiomatized the existence of the empty set).
With these axioms, it seems that we are in a position to define sets which have $n$ objects for any natural number- we just apply this union operation $n$ times. However, after these axioms have both been defined, Tao (after seemingly acknowledging this) says this is not the case:

This axiom allows us to define triplet sets, quadruplet sets, and so forth: if $a, b, c$ are three objects, we define $\{a, b, c\}:=\{a\} \cup\{b\} \cup\{c\}$; if $a, b, c, d$ are four objects, then we define $\{a, b, c, d\}:=\{a\} \cup\{b\} \cup\{c\} \cup\{d\}$, and so forth. On the other hand, we are not yet in a position to define sets consisting of $n$ objects for any given natural number $n$; this would require iterating the above construction " $n$ times", but the concept of $n$-fold iteration has not yet been rigorously defined. For similar reasons, we cannot yet define sets consisting of infinitely many objects, because that would require iterating the axiom of pairwise union infinitely often, and it is not clear at this stage that one can do this rigorously. Later on, we will introduce other axioms of set theory which allow one to construct arbitrarily large, and even infinite, sets.

Tao first seems like he is saying we can construct arbitrarily large sets, as by saying "so forth" in his first sentence, he seems like he is allowing that progression to get arbitrarily large through some sort of inductive progression. However, he then says that we are not able to do so yet, which confuses me. I do not understand why  we need more axioms to define these. These are the axioms he introduces after this (I do not understand why we need any of them to define arbitrarily large sets):

Axiom 3.6 (Axiom of specification). Let $A$ be a set, and for each $x \in A$, let $P(x)$ be a property pertaining to $x$ (i.e., for each $x \in A, P(x)$ is either a true statement or a false statement). Then there exists a set, called $\{x \in A: P(x)$ is true $\}$ (or simply $\{x \in A: P(x)\}$ for short), whose elements are precisely the elements $x$ in $A$ for which $P(x)$ is true.


Axiom 3.7 (Replacement). Let $A$ be a set. For any object $x \in A$, and any object $y$, suppose we have a statement $P(x, y)$ pertaining to $x$ and $y$, such that for each $x \in A$ there is at most one $y$ for which $P(x, y)$ is true. Then there exists a set $\{y: P(x, y)$ is true for some $x \in A\}$, such that for any object $z$,
$$
\begin{aligned}
z \in\{y & : P(x, y) \text { is true for some } x \in A\} \\
& \Longleftrightarrow P(x, z) \text { is true for some } x \in A .
\end{aligned}
$$


Axiom 3.8 (Infinity). There exists a set $\mathbf{N}$, whose elements are called natural numbers, as well as an object 0 in $\mathbf{N}$, and an object $n++$ assigned to every natural number $n \in \mathbf{N}$, such that the Peano axioms (Axioms 2.1-2.5) hold.

(Prior to Axiom $3.8$, Tao in the previous chapter included the assumption, marked as informal, that "There exists a number system $\mathbf{N}$, whose elements we
will call natural numbers, for which Axioms 2.1–2.5 [The Peano Axioms] are true", which makes me confused about the necessity of this axiom- are we not formally using this assumption?)

Axiom 3.10 (Regularity). If $A$ is a non-empty set, then there is at least one element $x$ of $A$ which is either not a set, or is disjoint from $A$.


Axiom 3.11 (Power set axiom). Let $X$ and $Y$ be sets. Then there exists a set, denoted $Y^X$, which consists of all the functions from $X$ to $Y$, thus
$$
f \in Y^X \Longleftrightarrow(f \text { is a function with domain } X \text { and codomain } Y) \text {. }
$$


Axiom 3.12 (Union). Let $A$ be a set, all of whose elements are themselves sets. Then there exists a set $\bigcup A$ whose elements are precisely those objects which are elements of the elements of $A$, thus for all objects $x$
$$
x \in \bigcup A \Longleftrightarrow(x \in S \text { for some } S \in A) \text {. }
$$

I do not understand why we needed further axioms than the ones we had at the point at which Tao said we needed more axioms in order to define arbitrarily large sets. What is the reason why we weren't able to construct arbitrarily large sets with only axioms 3.4 and 3.5?
EDIT: I now have 2 further things I am confused by with respect to the new axioms allowing us to define arbitrarily large sets:

why it is that even with the axioms, we can define arbitrarily large sets- we haven't yet defined the cardinality of sets and haven't defined an association between the size of a set and the natural numbers; we also haven't shown  a system satisfying the Peano axioms can describe the amount of elements in a set. Why is it the case that somehow axiom 3.8 allows us to do this and all the sudden induct on the number of elements in a set? We would need to show that elements of $\mathbf{N}$ can describe the amount of elements in a set first, right?

@Henry and @MichaelCarey said we can construct sets of large finite numbers,such as sets with a million elements, but not arbitrarily large sets- and I was thinking that we could just have a generic finite number $n$ which is a placeholder for any arbitrary number, and reason with $n$ the same we do any specific number, thereby constructing a set of arbitrarily large size; but @MichaelCarey said we need an axiom to generalize the use of our logic with a specific finite number to a generic number $n$- which axiom here does this, and why would we need an axiom to do this- it seems like just common sense?



As to 2, be very very careful with common sense. It's bound to lead you very far astray in set theory. The problem you're encountering is a tricky one, and at the place you are it's unlikely to be obvious it even is a problem. A very very handwavy reason why it's a problem is: "The $\mathbb{N}$ in the meta-theory need not be the same as the $\mathbb{N}$ in the theory." In other words it's not the same to be able to create a proof for any $n$ and to have a proof $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$.

@DRF: This post gives a more detailed explanation of your "handwavy reason".

To give a partial answer to 2 There is a sense in which it is obvious. Peano   even has Induction as an Axiom of Natural Numbers, which is really a main ingredient to generalizing n-iterations, and it's a commonly held belief that these Axioms are "obviously true/robust". It's just that from a Foundations perspective, we try to go deeper, and not make any formal assumptions about natural Numbers... instead we prove them, given some axioms about sets. The original vision for axioms, was that they  formalize common sense, As Zermelo put it, his axioms were "self-evidently true laws of thought"

There are reasons we want to avoid informal  common sense reasons. 1) They lead to paradoxes. Perhaps most famous are Zeno's conclusion that motion is impossible, and Russell's that The Set of all Sets which do not contain themsleves is actually not a set. 2) Computability, we cannot have a computer do mathematics for us by having common sense notions, we need formal notions if we want mathematics to be computible by a machine.

Notice the difference between:

the external statement "for every $n$, we can prove that there is a set with $n$ elements";
the internal statement "we can prove that, for every $n$, there is a set with $n$ elements".

The point of the induction principle/axiom is to internalise the first statement.

sorry I actually don't see any difference in meaning between the 2 statements- would you be able to elaborate?

The external version is a schema.  Given any n, you can construct a proof for one statement.  Given a different n, you can construct a different proof.  The internal one constructs one proof that works for all n.  This is particularly important if one is working on the assumption that proofs must be finite in length (I've not read Taos work).  Proving the external statement for all n may require infinite length.

@CortAmmon why doesn't the (finite) proof of the internal statement suffice as a proof of the external statement, as the statements are logically equivalent? So neither of these statements need have infinite proofs?

You can't do the internal proof until you have the induction axioms (internally).

@Ted why do we need to an internal proof, if the external proof proves that we can define a set with arbitrarily large amount of elements? (Tao says we can't define such a set). Why must we prove this in the scheme referred to by the internal proof; why doesn't the external proof of this suffice? (The propositions proved by each the external and internal proof seem logically equivalent). Also, how would the induction axioms be sufficient to do the internal proof; wouldn't we need to define "number of elements" in terms of natural numbers first?

There is not really one external proof; there is one such proof for each n. If you want to unify the external proofs into one proof, then you need an external induction on n. To then internalize this proof, you then need an internal induction axiom as well.

@Ted where in the axioms I laid out after Tao's explanation are we guaranteed the external and internal induction axioms?

The internal induction axiom is one of the Peano axioms, which you mentioned in 3.8 above but you didn't show. It is probably the last one, 2.5.

@Ted so is the idea that we don't know that any system of numbers exists which is inductive until we introduce axiom 3.8?

That's correct. Basically, using the axioms up to 3.5, you can prove that "there exists a set {a,b}" and "there exists a set {a,b,c}" and "there exists a set {a,b,c,d}", but you can't prove "there exists a set {a1, a2, ..., an}" because the concept of "n" and "..." don't exist yet until you introduce 3.8.

@Ted Also in addition to axiom 3.8, must we necessarily first define what the cardinality of a set is before we can reason that sets of $n$ elements for any $n$ exist? (As otherwise it seems undefined to talk about what it means for a set to have $n$ elements, even if we have axiom 3.8)

@Ted actually, in the preceding chapter, Tao had (as an assumption, not an axiom, which he labelled as informal) that there exists a set satisfying the Peano axioms. So I am not sure whether the lack of existence of a set satisfying Peano axioms is the reason why we could prove the existence of arbitrarily large sets anymore.

In a very informal sense, arbitrarily large sets and arbitrarily large proofs get squirley. Its very easy to come up with systems which are perfectly consistent for finite sets but which become inconsistent for larger sets (infinite sets), of which the set of natural numbers happens to be one. A lot of the challenge of these formal proofs is staying away from such undesirable behaviors. To answer your question, the internal proof (finite) can indeed be used to prove the external proof, but not the other way around. Proving the internal from the external may take an unbounded number of steps.

Ask yourself: can you write down a proof there exists a set with $1$ element? I'm sure that the answer is yes. Okay, so go write that proof down......
Now that you're done with that, ask yourself: can you write down a proof that there exists a set with $2$ elements? I'm sure that the answer is yes. So, okay, go write down that proof......
Next up: can you write down a proof that there exists a set with $3$ elements? I'm confident that you can, I'll wait while you write that proof down....
Okay, so, let's keep doing this until noon tomorrow? Okay? Then I have to go to a meeting. I'm sure you'll get up to some large number.
Oh? This is boring? Well, okay, here's a very different job for you: write down a proof that for every natural number $n$, there exists a set with $n$ elements.

I am extremely confused because your answer assumes that the natural numbers exist (by using $1$, $2$ as numbers) and also that we have defined cardinality of sets. Wouldn't we be able to use the axiom of induction if we knew that the natural numbers exist? I'm not sure whether you saw this in my post but prior to this point, Tao included as an assumption that the natural numbers exist, but not a rigorous axiom to this effect. Other comments have said that the problem is that we don't know that natural numbers exist, such as Ted's comment to the first answer

Well, you can do all of those tasks without ever assuming that the natural numbers exist; I was just using shorthand. Instead of writing down a proof that there exists a set with $1$ element, you can write down a proof that there exists a set $A$ such that the following sentence is true: $\exists a (a \in A, \text{and} , \forall b, (b \in A \implies b=a))$; that sentence says, in effect, $A$ is a set with $1$ element without ever actually meaning the existence of a natural numbers nor any particular element of the natural numbers.

And then I'm sure you can write down, and prove, a similar sentence which says, in effect, $A$ is a set with $2$ elements. And you can certainly continue on doing this until noon tomorrow.

thanks so is the correct way to view things- once we have axiom 3.8, we can define cardinalities of sets, and then use the axiom of induction to show for all $n$, there exists a set with $n$ elements, using only axioms 3.4 and 3.5 above? But prior to this point, we didn't know the naturals existed as a set, so we couldn't define cardinalities and induct on a number representing the cardinality?

I would say that's almost correct. Here's a slight amendment though. Using nothing but set theory, you can define what it means for two sets to have "the same cardinality", it means that there is a bijection between those two sets. You can then also formulate a definition of "finite cardinality" using nothing but set theory: it means that the set does not have "the same cardinality" as any of its proper subsets. But in order to have some kind of canonical "name" or "label" for the cardinality of a finite set, then yes, what you say in your comment is what one has to to.

Actually, is it possible to construct the naturals using sets (like von Neumann's definition of the naturals) and then just prove that the ensuing structure satisfied the Peano axioms? Meaning that we don't need to axiomatically assume that the naturals constitute a set in axiom 3.8?

Ah, but Von Neumann's definition implicitly uses a weak version of the axiom of infinity! It uses that weak version in order to guarantee the existence of the first infinite ordinal number, which one takes to be the definition of the natural numbers. In other words, the set theoretic axiom of infinity is used to prove Tao's "Axiom 3.8". Tao is taking a bit of a shorcut, to avoid getting into set theoretic cconcepts that are not particularly relevant to his development of analysis.

But the upshot is that you really do need some kind of set theoretic axiom to guarantee the existence of the natural numbers: either an up front statement of their existence, such as Tao's Axiom 3.8; or perhaps something slightly weaker.

FYI the Wikipedia page on the Axiom of Infinity is pretty good.

Actually, because Tao said "we are not yet in a position to define sets consisting of $n$ objects for any given natural number n", isn't he wrong because given $n$ explicitly, we can just define what it means for a set to have $n$ elements by using that shorthand technique you mentioned (It might just take a long time, but because $n$ is finite, it can be done?) By your shorthand technique,  I mean like when you said we can prove \exists a (a \in A, \text{and} , \forall b, (b \in A \implies b=a))- can't we just do this for any explicit $n$? As opposed to showing this $\forall n$

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Recall that the axioms tell us exactly what are sets: finite proofs resting on the axioms give us sets.  Nothing else is a set.  You will see that I use collection (and "not-set") for things which are not proven sets (at the various points of the development of the axioms).
So, you can make a sequence of finite proofs:

(I think you have the empty set...)  $\varnothing$ is a set.
$\{a\}$ is a set.
$\{a,b\}$ is a set.
...

Note that the ellipses are not a proof in the set theory.  They are an argument in a meta-theory, one which actually contains a copy ("model") of the naturals to act as a spine for the induction.
Now here's a mind-bender.  What proof can we write in the set theory up to Axiom 3.5 that the sequence of sets elided (by the ellipses) is actually modelled by the natural numbers.  It's some collection of sets only finitely many of which can appear in any proof.  Do we know that the naturals are so universal that the presumably infinite collection of sets parallels the naturals?  How do we know that?  How do we prove that using the axioms so far?  We don't.  Nothing in the theory up to Axiom 3.5 allows us to conclude any of that.
We have introduced a meta-theoretic/informal copy of the naturals in the preceding of Axiom 3.8, but it is worthwhile to note that we only ever use a finite initial segment of these informal naturals in any proof.  Nothing we do prior to Axiom 3.8 allows us to call the naturals a set.  Nor can we compare the entire infinite not-set of meta-theoretic natural numbers to the collection of sets we started to explicitly write down above.  (This collection of sets may or may not be a set.  Can you prove that it is using only the axioms up to Axiom 3.5?)
If we want our theory of sets to be able to reason about the entire collection of natural numbers, we need to import that collection into the theory.  And, it will be a big step since to that point, all sets have been finite.  So we introduce Axiom 3.8.  The naturals are now a set.  They weren't a set until we made an Axiom that said so.  Recall: the axioms tell us exactly what are sets: finite proofs resting on the axioms give us sets.  Since nothing in the preceding axioms gave us an infinite set, nothing in the preceding could prove that the naturals are an infinite set nor could reason about the informal collection of naturals.  We could reason about finite segments, but no finite proof about finite segments of the naturals will address the set-ness of the collection of all the informal naturals.
Once you have that the naturals are a set, then you can do most of the things you write that you want to do with them.  Until the naturals are a set, all the set theory theorems about sets do not apply to the naturals.
Then we can show that the usual models of the naturals as sets actually are models of the set of naturals from Axiom 3.8.  There has to be a set-thing that, from the axioms, is the naturals before this set theory can prove anything about that set-thing.

Thank you, before Tao's treatment of set theory, we included that the naturals are sets as an informal assumption, and I was wondering why couldn't just use this after axioms 3.4 and 3.5: for context, it was "Assumption 2.6 (Informal) There exists a number system $\mathbf{N}$, whose elements we will call natural numbers, for which Axioms 2.1-2.5 [The Peano Axioms] are true.
We will make this assumption a bit more precise once we have laid down our notation for sets and functions in the next chapter." So we couldn't use this because we didn't formally say it?

also, is part of the problem that (immediately after defining axioms 3.4 and 3.5) it is not well-defined to talk about what it means for a set to have $n$ elements, because 1. we have not proven that the naturals exist (the small segment thereof we used before, which you alluded to, was only a definition and we didn't have an axiom saying these existed)? and 2. we haven't defined cardinality of sets?

@PrincessMia : So, the Peano Axioms aren't axioms of set theory.  They don't assert that something is a set.  So a thing satisfying the Peano axioms isn't a set until we add a set theory axiom saying that it is.
$$  $$
This is the twin difficulty: we need enough theory of set functions to be able to define cardinality and equicardinality and then we need a model of (finite and minimally infinite) cardinalities to compare with.  Until the naturals are a set, we can't even write $n \in \Bbb{N}$ to pull out generic elements of that collection nor can we use them to label cardinalities.

@PrincessMia : So it's worth taking a moment to point out that the logical system used in your proofs is able to construct a version of a finite initial segment of the naturals.  This is why it is safe to have a "provisional" version of the naturals of which you only use a finite initial segment, don't try to reason about in its entirety, and don't pretend is a set.  So this initial segment of the naturals is as safe to use as your logical system is -- and if you can't trust your logical system, you can't trust any proof...

how do we know that the initial segment exists though, without axiom 3.8? Were we informally using the initial segment without any rigor? I am trying to understand why "this initial segment of the naturals is as safe to use as your logic system is"

@PrincessMia : Your logic system can express the idea of a distinguished (counting) object which is fairly labelled "$0$" and the idea of a function that allows one to progress from a (counting) object to a distinct successor (counting) object.  It is even expressive enough to allow defining arithmetic among those objects.  It can't extend this to all the integers because an infinite number of "this object, now labelled 5, is the unique result of the successor function applied to the object labelled 4" statements would require an infinitely long proof.  (continued...)

@PrincessMia : (...) Once again, we have to assert a little more than just logic (hello, Peano axioms) to get the full collection of naturals.  So you are informally using the safe initial segment that you can produce from your logic.  As long as your proofs stick to this safe segment, you are in good shape.  You still can't take "a generic element of the naturals" because "generic element of" is a relation where the right-hand member is a set.  Until the naturals are a set, you don't have any other way to pick out generic elements...

Actually, why do we have to say that there is a set where all the elements thereof are a system satisfying the Peano axioms- why can't we just say that there exists a number system satisfying the Peano axioms? Defining cardinality, and inducting, are things which only need a system of natural numbers, not a set of natural numbers, it seems to me. So it seems the assumption in the chapter preceding set theory, that there exists a system (not necessarily set) of natural numbers is actually sufficient to show that there exist arbitrarily large sets.

@PrincessMia : It's perfectly fine to have a number system satisfying the Peano axioms.  Do you ever want to write "Let $n \in \Bbb{N}$"?  Then $\Bbb{N}$ has to be a set because that is the semantics of the syntax "$\in$".  If you don't import $\Bbb{N}$ into your set theory, how to you get an infinite set from finite proofs?  Finally, you seem to persist in confusing "a finite initial segment of the naturals" with "arbitrarily large".  "Arbitrarily large" requires the ability to draw a generic natural from the naturals.  Which axiom allows that for sets and which allows it for not-sets?

You can prove any of these statements:

There is a set with 0 elements
There is a set with 1 element
There is a set with 2 elements
There is a set with 3 elements
There is a set with 4 elements
$\ldots$

You cannot prove this statement:

Given $n$, there is a set with $n$ elements

In that statement, the input $n$ is an abstract element that has to be dealt with in the proof. You don't have the ability yet to handle this abstract quantity $n$.

The principal of mathematical induction Axiom 2.5 is in the previous chapter, and Tao does not introduce this to his set theory until Axiom 3.8 (Axiom 3.7 in my edition).  He does not need this for specific large unions (e.g. those made with a million unions) but he does for arbitrarily large finite numbers of unions.
The same axiom gives him an infinite set $\mathbf N$, but does not yet imply the possibility of a infinite number of unions.  Axiom 3.12 (3.11 in my edition) gives this and so arbitrarily large numbers of unions more generally.

2 questions: 1. Don't we actually need to define cardinalities for sets (define a correspondence between the natural numbers and the size of a set) before we can start to prove that we can construct arbitrarily large sets, such that even axiom 3.8 (3.7 for you) isn't sufficient? 2. regarding how axiom 3.12 is stronger than axiom of 3.5- if $A$ is an infinite set,  why can't we just take its union once with the empty set using axiom 3.5, and then use the axiom of replacement to replace the sets with their elements, getting the same result as infinitely applying the union to the elements of $A$?

also, Tao in the previous chapter, in what was marked as an informal assumption, stated that there exists a set satisfying the Peano axioms. So why do we need axiom 3.8- is it because this axiom isn't rigorous enough?

I think the book chose to present natural numbers before sets for pedagogical reasons, but in formal logic it is customary to define sets using the ZF axioms first and then construct natural numbers using sets. The book teaches analysis, not formal logic, so if you want a more rigorous presentation you may be better served with a different book.

Most answers are highlighting the distinction between $\forall n, \vdash P(n)$ versus $\vdash\forall n, P(n)$, where $\vdash P(n)$ means "there is a proof of $P(n)$". While this distinction is very important, it's not entirely applicable in this context.
It turns out that the axioms 3.4 and 3.5 (together with Extensionality and Empty Set) are sufficient to define an infinite wellorder, and to prove the singular statement encoding the fact that we have arbitrarily large collections. The wellordering property is substantially weaker without the principle of Specification, but it's still clear that we prove the existence of arbitrarily large sets.
It's entirely possible that Tao didn't know about the construction I referenced, as the details are rather subtle. It's more likely, however, that he was simply saying that the notions of "iteration" and "natural number" were not properly defined at that particular point in his formalization. His statements were very vague, so it's hard to nail down exactly what he was trying to say, so it's really not your fault for being confused by it.


To clarify why $\forall n \vdash P(n)$ didn't necessarily imply $\vdash \forall n P(n)$, was it because $\vdash P(n)$ doesn't necessarily imply $P(n)$ because we didn't assume that our proof is a valid proof? I am trying to understand the ways in which our proof system can be not sound, as you said we are assuming our proof system is sound by saying $\forall n \vdash P(n) \implies \vdash \forall n P(n)$. Was it instead the absence of the axiom of induction which rendered our proof system not sound enough to show $\forall n \vdash P(n) \implies \vdash \forall n P(n)$?

@PrincessMia The problem isn't that provability doesn't imply truth, the problem is that truth doesn't imply provability. A proof is just a finite string of symbols, obeying certain validity requirements simple enough to be verified by a computer. The statement $\forall n, \vdash P(n)$ basically says there's an infinite schema of proofs, one for each $n$, but there's no requirement those proofs be related. If you are still confused, you may need to post a new question specifically about proof theory.

Some other previous answers wrongly claim that Tao's excerpt implies that we can prove "there is a set with 2 elements". No. $\{a,b\}$ may not have 2 elements, unless you can prove $a ≠ b$. It's unclear whether Tao himself made this mistake, since his excerpt is actually a bit ambiguous.
Nevertheless, the point is that even if you can write down a property $Q$ and prove that it holds for every explicit natural number (i.e. "$0$" or of the form "$1+\cdots+1$"), it does not imply that you can prove "$∀k{∈}ℕ \ ( \ Q(k) \ )$"!
That is, it is possible that you can prove "$Q(0)$" and "$Q(1)$" and "$Q(1+1)$" and "$Q(1+1+1)$" and so on, but cannot prove "$∀k{∈}ℕ \ ( \ Q(k) \ )$"! This is not due to any defect in logical reasoning but instead is a fundamental phenomenon. Given any foundational system $F$ for mathematics, which we use for all our proofs, if $F$ can prove all the basic properties of natural numbers (i.e. that $⟨ℕ,0,1,+,·,<⟩$ forms a discrete ordered semiring), then we can in fact write down an explicit property $C$ and prove (within $F$) that $F$ proves "$C(0)$" and "$C(1)$" and "$C(1+1)$" and "$C(1+1+1)$" and so on and either $F$ proves "$0 = 1$" or $F$ cannot prove "$∀k{∈}ℕ \ ( \ C(k) \ )$"! This is a direct consequence of the Gödel-Rosser incompleteness theorem (for which you can read a relatively simple proof here).
By the way, relying on "common sense" is often foolish in mathematics; unless you can perform exceptionally clear logical thinking, your "common sense" is likely to be flawed, in which case the easiest way to avoid fallacies is by using rigorous logical reasoning and not intuition.

I believe Tao, by this point has established that the empty set is a set, and so with Pairing, we can construct two unique sets a,b, which by another application of pairing form a set with exactly two elements. At least, that's what I assume people are assuming/referencing. You make a excellent point though, that absent such a previous development, it really does seem a bit ambiguous.

@MichaelCarey: Yes I know we can do that, but I don't think most readers of this thread realized that (prior to my post). Thanks for your comment though!

I had a question about your first point- in axiom 3.4, Tao refers to how "$y \in A$ if and only if $y=a$", meaning the equals operation has been defined on whatever objects we have. So wouldn't we able to say that because $a \neq b$ has been defined (maybe we can't prove what it is though, but there exists a value such that this value is $a \neq b$), there exists a set with 2 elements? (cont.)

(continued) However, Tao says "we are not yet in a position to define sets consisting of $n$ objects for any given natural number n", meaning that we are not even able to show the existence of a set of size $n$ given $n$ explicitly- but isn't this wrong because we could define any set of size $n$ given $n$ explicitly if we have $=$?

@PrincessMia: No. How can you anyhow conclude that there exists objects a,b such that a ≠ b? If you just think a little bit more, it should be clear that just because a concept has been defined doesn't imply that there is an instance of it. We can define a squarootwo as a rational number whose square is equal to 2, but no squarootwo exists!

@PrincessMia: For your second question, also no, because you haven't proven it. You can claim all you like that something is obviously true by common sense, but until you have an actual rigorous proof, it remains nothing more than just a claim. Of course, claims in some field by people who demonstrate competency in that field should be taken more seriously than claims by other people, but it still needs verification if feasible.


"Any object" does not include any object we can think of (what if it's a paradoxical object?) It includes any object we can show exists by using the axioms we have available.

Axiom 3.12 implies Axiom 3.5 (if we have the pairing axiom) because if we let $A = \{B, C \}$, then $\cup A = B \cup C$. Axiom 3.5 does not imply Axiom 3.12 but says that if we have two sets their union is a set; Axiom 3.12 says that if we have a set $A$, the set made by taking the union of all the elements of $A$ is a set.


Axiom 3.12 gives us that if $\{a,b,c, \ldots \}$ is a set, then $a \cup b \cup c  \ldots$ is a set.
The set $A$ may be infinite, and no finite amount of applications of Axiom 3.5 can produce the repeated union of all the elements of $A$.
Meta-mathematically, we can construct sets to be arbitrarily large finite cardinalities.
If we need a set with $50$ elements, we know how to construct such a set. And we can intuit that such a process can work for any finite cardinality.
But can we prove, on the basis of the axioms, that there exists a set with arbitrary amounts of elements?
Furthermore, how do we reason about infinite sets? Does our intuition work with infinite sets? Don't we need some rigorous method for dealing with infinite sets/constructions, where our intuitions don't extend to?
Does the Axiom of Union + Axiom of Set Existence + Axiom of Pairing prove that there exist sets of arbitrary size?
Sure, we can 1-by-1 construct increasingly bigger sets.
But, can you write out a proof of the existence of a set of cardinality ${{10^{\text{google}}}^{\text{google}}}^{\text{google}}$? - Even if you could write on individual atoms, there aren't enough in the Observable Universe to produce such a proof.
For that, we need some kind of Recursion Theorem, which is the point of the additional axioms.
Also, sure, you can construct a set of some cardinality $n$, but can you construct a set of arbitrary finite cardinality?
However big you construct, you can never cover all possible sizes in a finitely long proof by taking one union pair at a time, and so you cannot prove that such an object exists.

regarding how axiom 3.12 is stronger than axiom of 3.5- if $A$ is an infinite set,  why can't we just take its union once with the empty set using axiom 3.5, and then use the axiom of replacement to replace the sets with their elements, getting the same result as taking the union of the elements of $A$ an infinite amount of times?

Replacement is a very powerful axiom, with Replacement I imagine with just 3.5 you dont need 3.12, using a procedure like you suggest. I don't think Tao's development Is maximally efficient in terms of minimizing the axioms necessary.

What is the reason why we can't use the reasoning we employ for a certain finite number (in your example 50, when you said we can reason a set with 50 elements exists) to argue in general, by letting $n$ be a place holder for any finite number, and argue that a set of $n$ elements exists using the same exact reasoning we used to argue that a set of 50 elements exists? Tao says that "n-fold interaction has not yet been rigorously defined"; but what is the difference between n-fold iteration, and iterating just a few times like he did in  his earlier examples?

To formally argue a set of 50 elements exists, we actually construct such a set, it might be a long proof but we can do it. How long would a proof that shows a length of size n be? Could we ever actually write it down? We can't write down a proof for the size of a set of size 10^google, so we can't do it for size n. When would we stop the construction? How do we know when we reach n? after n many steps? how many is that?

To formally argue the construnction works in  general, we need a theorem which says that generalzing is such a way is a legitimare argument ( provable from the axioms)- This theorem is called the recursion theorem, or what Tao calls n-fold recursion, or recusion on natural numbers.

n-fold iteration isn't just a  definition, it's a definition and a theorem. Using the axioms you prove there is such a construction, such that you can iterate a process as much as you want, given some restrictions. In practice, this is most powerful when we construct things which are built by infinitely many iterations... so no amount of finite iterations could get us there.

So, really the biggest differenfe between n-fold iteration and iterating a few times, is that n-fold iteration generalizes to infinite sets , and we can actually write out a formal proof using n-fold iteration to say a set of size 10^googol exists. ( In this case we don't! construct it explicitly we use a theorem about n-fold iteration, which says it exists)

Thanks what is the reason why the additional axioms which Tao provides guarantee n-fold interaction? Also, how does n-fold iteration generalize to infinite sets, if we are iterating a finite number n of times?

Im not informed about exactly which axioms one needs to prove particular statements. For n-fold iteration on natural numbers, I know you need an Inductive Set, so the infinity axiom, and you use functions, so you need replacement to have that the cartesian product of sets is a set. Im not sure exactly what else is required.

It generalizes, because instead of n-fold iteration, ( where n is a natural number) you prove that α-iteration - where α is an ordinal, works, And they are basically the same argument, just thay ordinals can be infinite. This works, because jusy like how you can use induction on ntural numbers, you can induct on ordinals- this is called transfinite induction, - and is a integral part of the proof for recursion, or α - iteration

@MichaelCarey: The asker is confused about really basic stuff (due to the utterly confusing nature of Tao's book), so I don't think it is helpful to talk about ordinals at all...

@user21820 Should I delete the comment chain? I don't know of a simpler way to answer the question, about how recursion can generalize to infinite sets, but I definitely don't want to confuse anybody.

@MichaelCarey: No need to delete it. I'm just suggesting avoiding any transfinite induction or ordinals at this level. The excerpt does not talk about infinite iteration either; it just says that we can later see how to construct n-fold iteration and even infinite sets (not stated to be by iteration). =)
